# What are characteristics or qualifications of a righteous scholar of religion in Islam?

Tags: islamic-scholar, government

Inspired by [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56684/), which was closed down due to being judgemental about groups of people, I decided to ask it in a general voice.

What are the characteristics and qualifications of religious scholars especially with respect to their relationship with governments and the laymen?

Should the clerics be supported by governments, people or rely on their own income? What should be their standard of living? Can they live luxurious lives?

Comment: Too many questions in one post

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I edited the post removing the last questions.

Comment: Well the modified question looks like one you've basically answered a few years ago.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, hmm, not sure I remember it.